# How to launch external opened app using custom URL scheme from Ionic App?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, app-launcher

I want to launch opened app B externally from ionic app A using custom URL scheme.

**Solutions Tried**

1. Plugin **In App Browser**, is able to launch external app in the ionic app itself instead of launching the opened external app.

```
const target = '_system';
    let url = 'abc123://abc.com/mobile/details/' + Id;

    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      zoom: 'no',
      location: 'no',
      hidden: 'yes'
    };

    this.loadingProvider.dismiss();
    this.inAppBrowserRef = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, target, options);
```

2. Plugin **App Launcher**. For android, it is able to launch external app but use package name instead of custom URL scheme

Answer (score 0):

I use an anchor tag in my template, and set `target="_blank"`. This is from an Ionic 5 app, but I've only tested in the full iOS build, I don't have an Android one yet.  I'm also using Capacitor, but I don't think that changes the browser behavior.

```html
<a [href]="website" target="_blank">{{ website }}</a>
```

The `target="_blank"` causes it to open the URL in the main os browser. The main browser should then handle your custom link.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However I cannot use anchor tag. I need to pass dynamic param to the custom link, therefore I need to handle it in .ts page. InAppBrowser & App Launcher I've tried and all of them will launch app B in ionic app A itself instead of launch app B externally that already opened.

Comment: My href was dynamic as well, its set at the component initialization, but there is no reason that my `website` variable couldn't change over time based on other inputs.  `window.open` should try and open in a new "tab" like `target="_blank"` does, but I can't verify right now.

Comment: ```window.open``` will add "http" in front of my custom URL in android and causing ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom URL to open use

```
window.open('Your URL','_system');
```

in your code. This can be work in both platform Android and ios Perfectly.